# Android RecyclerView Negative Offset

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a timeline similar to Google Nest Camera timeline, I'm using a `recyclerview` which I want all rows to be the same height, therefore, for a row with an image, I'm using offset, however, when scrolling, since it is a negative scroll, the image appears/disappear of all of the sudden, here is a gif

https://media.giphy.com/media/3DZApAZd284aVPWVGu/giphy.gif

Is there a way to make the row load before appearing on the screen?

recyclerview initialize

```
  timelineRecyclerView.apply {
        addItemDecoration(OverlapDecoration(-15.toDp()))
        adapter = timelineAdapter
        val lm = layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
        lm.reverseLayout = true
        lm.stackFromEnd = true
        layoutManager = lm
        
    }
```

ItemDecoration for offset:

```
    class OverlapDecoration(val offset: Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, itemPosition: Int, parent: RecyclerView) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "${parent.adapter?.getItemViewType(itemPosition) }")

        when( parent.adapter?.getItemViewType(itemPosition) ) {
            1 -> {}
            2 -> { outRect.set(0, offset, 0, offset) }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please show your code where RecyclerView is initialized? Also, what offset are you using?

Comment: @Nulldroid thank you, I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all rows to have the same height, you can use

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
```

for optimization.

To pre-load items and keep them in cache, you can use

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(3)     // example: 3 items will be held in cache off-screen.
```

If this does not work, you can implement a custom LayoutManager to pre-cache items. [This example](https://androiddevx.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/recycler-view-pre-cache-views/) is a bit older, but it should still work. Not tested though.

Comment: I tried adding the fixed size and cache size, but still same. I will try the pre-cache.